# create popup using silverlight and add a data grid to the popup

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, popup

I need to add a grid to a popup in Silverlight project. I have added this code in the mainpage.xaml.cs file I have created a popup.
but I need to add a grid showing a table from the database.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        popup p = new Popup();Border border = new Border();
        border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5.0);

        StackPanel panel1 = new StackPanel();
        panel1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);

        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Close";
        button1.Margin = new Thickness(2.0);
        button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click);
        TextBlock textblock1 = new TextBlock();
        textblock1.Text = "The popup control";
        textblock1.Margin = new Thickness(5.0);
        panel1.Children.Add(textblock1);
        panel1.Children.Add(button1);
        border.Child = panel1;

        Grid grid1 = new Grid();
        // i need to bind this grid to data from the sql database and attach this grid to the  popup     


        // Set the Child property of Popup to the border 
        // which contains a stackpanel, textblock and button.
        p.Child = border;
        p.DataContext = 
        // Set where the popup will show up on the screen.
        p.VerticalOffset = 200;
        p.HorizontalOffset = 300;

        // Open the popup.
        p.IsOpen = true;


    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you looking for how to [bind to DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control)? Or does the `Popup` not support `DataGrids` as children element? Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Actually i am a beginner with Silverlight. It would be great if i can do both. ie bind to datagrid and add that datagrid to the popup.

Comment: when i click a button, a popup should appear showing a table containing data from the database..

Comment: Have you tried to search for: How to bind to DataGrid? and How to add DataGrid as child element programmatically?. I am sure that there are a lot of info on these issues.

Comment: Ya. i have done the binding part to the datagrid. in a WPF application. But i need a Silverlight application where i can add this datagrid as the child window of a popup. i have searched a lot. but couldn't find the correct results. Could you please suggest some useful links?

Comment: Hmm, I am too mostly a WPF guy, but do you say that `panel1.Children.Add(grid);` fails to add the grid? And there are a lot of net tutorials - https://www.google.com/#q=silverlight+datagrid+datasource+binding+programmatically (not all of them deal with database table, but if you know how to read tables from db, you will be able to make them suit your needs). So, basically, there are three nearly non-related questions: 1. How to add DataGrid in Silverlight popup 2. How to read table data from database 3. How to bind data to DataGrid in Silverlight. Just deal with each of them individually.

Answer (score 0):

The Grid is a layout control, and not for displaying tables. For tabular data, you'll need a DataGrid control.

```
List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();

var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = customerList;

Popup popup = new Popup();
popup.Child = dataGrid;
popup.IsOpen = true;
```